# Geometry triangles

Tags: geometry

$x, y, z$ are integer that are side of an obtuse-angled triangle. If $xy = 4$
How can the value of z be determined.
Is there any approach or a proof by which we can get the result.

Comment: you certainly have two isosceles triangles of sides $2,2,1$ and $4,4,1.$

Comment: @abel neither of which is obtuse.  for 2,2,z to be obtuse, z^2 > 2^2 + 2^2 and by triangle ineq. z <x+y so $\sqrt{8} < z < 4$ so z = 3.  and 2,2,3 is acceptable.  If x,y = 1,4 we by triangle ineqs.  z < 1+4 and z > 4 -3 so z = 4 but that is isoceles so the base angles are accute we nee $1 > 4^2 + 4^2$ which is obviousy not the case.  So 2,2,3 is the only possiblity.

Comment: @fleablood, thanks. i forgot the obtuse angle requirement.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy=4\to (x,y)\in \{(1,4),(2,2),(4,1)\}$$

$1)$ $(x,y)=(1,4)$ or $(x,y)=(4,1)$

By the triangle inequality we have $4-1<z<1+4$ and then $z=4$, which is not a obtuse triangle because:

$$4^2<4^2+1^2$$

$2)$ $(x,y)=(2,2)$

By the triangle inequality we have $2-2<z<2+2$ and then $z\in \{1,2,3\}$

Clearly, if $z=1$ or $z=2$ we don't have a obtuse triangle then $z=3$ and here have:

$$3^2>2^2+2^2$$

what give us an obtuse triangle. So $(x,y,z)=(2,2,3)$

Comment: @Mary Lopez: Is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y$ are integers and $xy= 1$ then $x,y = 2,2$ or $1,4$. Using the cosine rule for both cases

Case $1$: 
$$z^2 = 1^2 + 4^2 - 8\cos(\theta)$$
$$z^2 = 17 - 8\cos\theta $$
Since $|\cos \theta| \le 1$
$$ z^2 \in [11,25]$$
Then the possible values for which $z$ is an integer and $z^2 \in [11,25]$ are $4$ and $5$.

Now you have to test that these give you an obtuse angled triangle. for the case $z = 5$ you have $\cos \theta = -1 \implies \theta = 180$ not possible.  If you had $z = 4$ then $\theta = 82^o$ and since its isosceles then we know its not obtuse.

Do the same for case 2 and youll have your solution